# Force Visual Studio 2017 to use a specific Android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I deploy a Xamarin/Android app in VS 2017, it uses the default "VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone" emulator. This emulator is buggy on my system and crashes with strange errors. I've managed to install another faster x86 Atom emulator. How do I force VS 2017 to use this emulator?

[image: emulator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is stupid. All I had to do was drop down the Debug button and select the emulator I want to deploy to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[U can select the default device here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQuo6.png)

From then on that project will always use that emulator.